# Create Success\Error page like SharePoint pages

Tags: publishing-page, 2007, development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom Error Page for SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2129/custom-error-page-for-SharePoint)

hi..

i want to create a success/error application page which look like SharePoint success/error page, and it write the exception if an error occurs and on success write the success message.

does any one have idea how to create application page which look like SharePoint error page.

thanks
SAAD

Comment: @sbtahir: Please don't ask the same question twice. Instead, edit your original question with additional information. This will also bump it to the top of the stack. Thanks and welcome to SharePoint Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

Are u looking at this??

SPLongOperation operation = new SPLongOperation(this.Page)