# Custom Error Page for SharePoint

Tags: application-pages

We've created an Application Page which configure database for custom modules. We've designed this Application Page with SharePoint custom control.

There are some errors which can be occurred when user configure database, for example, database server not found etc. How should we design an Application which should be similar to SharePoint Error Pages.

Or Is there any better way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear the purpose of "similar to SharePoint Error Page". If you can/want you can reusre SharePoint error page by using *SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage()*. If you need some customisations - then I beleave you must create something yorself ..

Answer (score 2):

I believe if the exception caught by the page inherits from SPException, the message in the exception will be displayed on the normal error page.